# Is winSCP available for mac or only windows?

Tags: mac, windows, ftp

I need a ftp for mac since my current viper ftp is corrupting my xml files. So just wanted to know if we have efficient FTP for mac users.

Comment: SCP and FTP are two different things.  Which one are you referring to?  Also, both clients are built in.  Are you looking for a GUI?

Comment: I read apple dropped ftp in High Sierra in favor of sftp.  http://osxdaily.com/2018/08/07/get-install-ftp-mac-os/

Comment: See [Is there a tool like WinSCP for MacOS?](https://superuser.com/q/255613/213663)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no native WinSCP.

[Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io) is a free option.

[Transmit](https://www.panic.com/transmit/) (Paid) is *the* FTP client for macOS.